# Ansible variable assignment using URI & XML modules

Tags: xml, ansible, uri

I am new to Ansible/Jinja, so this is probably a basic question.  I am using the Core URI module to make a REST API call to a network device as follows:

```
---
- name: Test PAN API
  hosts: fw
  connection: local 
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
  - name: Calling API System Info 
    action: uri url=https://192.168.1.10/api/?type=op&cmd=<show><system><info></info></system></show>&key=thisismysecretkey return_content=yes validate_certs=no
    register: result
  - name: Set variable  
    set_fact: sysinfo="{{ result.content }}”
  - name: Parsing XML response
    action: xml xmlstring="{{ sysinfo }}" xpath=//system/* content=text
    register: hn
  - debug: var=hn.matches['hostname']
```

I’d like to parse each of the xml nodes into variables such that hostname=PA-VM, etc.  Here is what the response looks like:

```
TASK [debug var=sysinfo] *******************************************************
ok: [pan] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "sysinfo": "<response status=\"success\"><result><system><hostname>PA-VM</hostname><ip-address>192.168.1.10</ip-address><netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask></system></result></response>"
}

TASK [Testing XML] *************************************************************
ok: [pan]

TASK [debug var=hn.matches] ****************************************************
ok: [pan] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "hn.matches": [
        {
            "hostname": "PA-VM"
        }, 
        {
            "ip-address": "192.168.1.10”
        }, 
        {
            "netmask": "255.255.255.0"
        }
    ]
}
```

I’ve experimented with different Jinja filters, but I feel as though I am missing something simple.  It appears that hn.matches is a list, with each key value pair a string.  For example, if I...

```
 - debug: var=hn.matches[0]
```

I get...

```
TASK [debug var=hn.matches[0]] *************************************************
ok: [pan] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "hn.matches[0]": {
        "hostname": "PA-VM"
    }
}
```

What would be really great is...

```
set_fact: hn="{{ response.result.system.hostname }}"
```

Just looking for the cleanest / best way without using regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of `map` and `select` filters:

```
- debug: msg="{{ hn.matches | map(attribute='hostname') | select('defined') | first }}"
```

Comment: Thank you - that did it!

Answer (score 0):

I just added XML parsing support in the uri module because I needed it too.
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/53045

Just like the JSON support, it will return an 'xml' key with a dictionary consisting of the XML content for the convenience of accessing the data in the payload.

Your example would look like this:

```
 - name: Calling API System Info 
   uri:
     url: https://192.168.1.10/api/?type=op&cmd=<show><system><info></info></system></show>&key=thisismysecretkey
     return_content=yes
     validate_certs=no
register: result

  - debug:
      var: result.xml
```

The output in result.xml would be:

```
{
    'response': {
        '@status': 'success',
        'result': {
            'system': {
                'hostname': 'PA-VM',
                'ip-address': '192.168.1.10',
                'netmask': '255.255.255.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there's more than one system-entry, it would return a list of entries.